# How to find users with age more than 20 years and under 25 years of database php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a problem in taking the database with the age of more and less than the value I choose

Currently the database for sample age format is "1996-07-30"

And I want to retrieve user data with filter age more than 20 and less than 25 years

I've tried some queries and it does not work, and here's an example code I created :

```
SELECT *
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, tglLahir, CURDATE()) AS age 
  FROM tb_member 
 WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, tglLahir, CURDATE()) >= 20 
   AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, tglLahir, CURDATE()) <= 25 
 ORDER 
    BY nama
 LIMIT 0,10
```

and I've also tried another example like this:

```
SELECT *
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, tglLahir, CURDATE()) AS age 
   FROM `tb_member`  
  WHERE tglLahir BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 YEAR) 
    AND DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 30 YEAR)
  ORDER 
     BY nama
  LIMIT 0,10
```

but still no results, is there any other solution to solve this problem ?

**UPDATE**

I solve my problem, i still use this code :

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, tglLahir, CURDATE()) >= '20' AND 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, tglLahir, CURDATE()) <= '25'
```

And work perfectly, thanks for anyone answer my question, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like using `DATE_SUB()` to calculate for this purpose (use DATE_SUB to subtract from NOW() to get 20 years ago, then 25 years ago). Combined with BETWEEN you should be able to do:

```
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, tglLahir, CURDATE()) AS age 
FROM `tb_member` WHERE 
tglLahir BETWEEN 
DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 20 YEAR) AND
DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 25 YEAR)
ORDER BY `nama` LIMIT 0,10
```

Your second query example in your question is close, but you use `date` in your second `DATE_SUB()` which I think may be the culprit in your problem with this approach.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when i change the year number from 20 to 23 but user with age 21 still exist, how can this happen ?

Comment: Select 2 between 3 and 1

Comment: @IvanJuliant that can't happen.... what is the birthdate tglLahir for this age 21 record? And are you adding any other WHERE clause to the query, or using it just like above?

Comment: I'll try again. Nothing happened between 1998 and 1993 - in the same way that nothing happens between 3 and 1.